# jade android for native application

Tags: android, agents-jade

I'm looking for a way to develop a native android application ( with no server to run agents in ) . Is there a way to run an agent inside android and not like the jade fpr android tutorial chat application , where the platform is installed on server ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider another Java-based agent platform such as [Janus](http://www.janus-project.org/Home), where you can deploy and run agents without the need for a central server/container.

See this page: [First Janus on Android Tutorial](http://www.janus-project.org/First_Janus_On_Android_Tutorial)

Comment: I tried to build an example application through android adt (downloaded from android home page). But I can't deploy my app, my eclipse always get "out of memory" error. have you got this problem?

Comment: Eclipse is running out of memory? You may have to increase the heap size: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F